# How to remove whitespace, unwanted chars from list to compare string values c#

Tags: c#, list

I have a list, lets say  `unknownChars` which contains a a number of strings 'Unknown', 'TBC', 'TBA' etc, which are needed for user validation.

I need to check if the string entered exists within my lists, however I need to to be aware of all possibilities, such as casing, and extra character such as 'UUknown' and special characters such as N/A. I'm assuming I will need to first of all normalize the input, to remove any whites spacing and any other characters entered by mistake and then process the input to see if the nomrilised string is a match.

```
public bool useUnkownPack(string strTest)
{
    List<string> unkownChars = new List<string> {'Unknown', 'TBC', 'TBA', "N/A"}
    if(unkown.Contains(strTest, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnorcase))
    {
       return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

So if someone could point me in the right direction  how to normilise the input   out any any unwanted characters before i match its I would be very grateful

Comment: If you just want to detect whether one or more of many strings is present in a string, use a case-insensitive regex like `[unknown|tbc|tba|n/a]` and return whether the input matches the regex?

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful    This is a multi Win Form app which contains three forms, which the user will have to fll out with  their infomaton. my iuuse is that o It will pass validation if whitespace is before the entered word. I also need the obool to return false if any special chars exist

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your list of items has all normalised, character-only values. Then use regex to remove any non alpha characters.

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z]");
Console.WriteLine(useUnkownPack(rgx.Replace(inputValue, "")));

....

public static bool useUnkownPack(string strTest)
{
    List<string> unkownChars = new List<string> {"Unknown", "TBC", "TBA", "NA"};

    if(unkownChars.Contains(strTest, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
       return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/QFCW63817

Comment: Cheers for your response, should i  use the created regex in all of validating events  or  within the useKownPack function?

Comment: @dave.2 to be fair, and differing from my example, you should probably do that once inside your method.